# eslint selector syntax for nth child argument

Tags: css-selectors, eslint, rules

am trying to match the following in a custom lint rule:

`expect(element.getAttribute('checked')).toBe(true);`

i'm attempting to use the following syntax in the selector:

```
    "CallExpresssion[callee.object.arguments[0].callee.property.name='getAttribute']"(node) {
      console.log(node);
    },
```

but this doesn't work because of the `arguments[0]`. so i'm wondering if there's any way to do this query on an argument.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to access items in an array. The syntax is not really what you'd expect though. Instead of the normal bracket notation, you'd access it as a property: `arguments.0`

This is what your query could look like:

```
"CallExpresssion[callee.object.arguments.0.callee.property.name='getAttribute'](node) {
  console.log(node);
}
```